# Log4Net VB log files issue

Tags: vb.net, log4net

Yesterday i implemented log4net in my VB.NET web project, and worked well. But today someone updated the project and it doesnt work anymore.
My Assemblyinfo.vb:

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFileExtension:="Log4net", Watch:=True)>
```

Log4net.config:

```
    <logger additivity="false" name="Access">

      <level value="INFO" />

      <appender-ref ref="Accesos" />

    </logger>   

    <appender name="GeneralAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <file value="D:\Logs\LOG3.log" />

      <appendToFile value="true" />

      <rollingStyle value="Composite"  />

      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />

      <maximumFileSize value="100K" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">

        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] - [%logger] %message%newline" />

      </layout>

    </appender>


    <appender name="Access" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">

      <file value="D:\Logs\LOG2.log" />

      <appendToFile value="true" />

      <rollingStyle value="Composite"  />

      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />

      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />

      <maximumFileSize value="100K" />

      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">

        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] - [%logger] %message%newline" />

      </layout>
   </appender>   
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

In my aspx

```
import log4net
...
 log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()

    Dim logger As ILog = Nothing

    logger = LogManager.GetLogger("GeneralAppender")

    logger.InfoFormat("test")
```

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, the issue is in `ConfigFileExtension` property.

As log4net [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Config.XmlConfiguratorAttribute.ConfigFileExtension.html) says:

> If the ConfigFileExtension is set to MyExt then possible config file
>   names would be: MyConsoleApp.exe.MyExt or MyClassLibrary.dll.MyExt

So, change your Assemblyinfo.vb to this:

```
<Assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile:="Log4net.config", Watch:=True)>
```

P.S. I've never used VB, so be careful